# Convert global issue ID to project issue ID

Tags: youtrack, youtrack-api

When I query the API `api/issues/` for issues with `fields="id"`, I get back an array of issues similiar to this:

```
[
  { "id": "2-120" }
]
```

This works for further calls because `2-120` can be used in calls to `/api/issues/{id}`. However, I also need to display those IDs to users, which are more comfortable with project-based IDs, like `EX-10`. (Also, the whole browser user-interface is structured around those project issues ids)

What I tried:

- Had a look at the [Issue JSON Schema docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/incloud/api-json-schema.html#Issue), which do not seem to contain an additional ID
- Tried to find out if they can be converted manually, which does not seem to be the case.

So, how can I convert global issue IDs, like `2-120`, to project issue IDs, like `EX-10`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at the schema again, I simply overlooked `idReadable`. So, a request to `api/issues/PA-102?fields=id,idReadable` will give you both types of IDs.

```
{ "id": "2-120", "idReadable": "PA-20" }
```